# Why splatting not working if we direcly write Hash table?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, dsl

Powershell splatting works if we pass parameter as below.

```
    $Vm = @{ 
       Name = "NewVm"
       MemoryStartupBytes = 1GB
       NewVHDPath = d:\vhd\base.vhdx
   }
    New-VM @VM
```

But if tried as below it doesn't work.

```
    New-VM @{ 
       Name = "NewVm"
       MemoryStartupBytes = 1GB
       NewVHDPath = d:\vhd\base.vhdx
   }
```

Also i tried

```
    New-VM @( @{ 
       Name = "NewVm"
       MemoryStartupBytes = 1GB
       NewVHDPath = d:\vhd\base.vhdx
   }
  )
```

Here also Hash table is being created (unnamed hash table ). But why it doesn't accept? Is there any trick to make it believe it is splatting variable?

One trick is to write a proxy as below.

```
    function New-myVM
    {
        param
        (
            [Hashtable] $ht
        )

        New-VM @ht

    }

    New-MyVM @{ 
       Name = "NewVm"
       MemoryStartupBytes = 1GB
       NewVHDPath = d:\vhd\base.vhdx
   }
```

But if we do this way then each command require proxy which is heavy.

If it can be written like this , It can look like DSL. So i am trying to figure out a way.

Comment: May I ask why you'd like to do it that way? I thought splatting has been made to make the code easier to read if you have a lot of parameters to provide for one cmdlet. If you like to provide the parameters on the same line you could just use normal way.

Comment: @Olaf I have formatted my question. Instead of creating a separate variable and then call it using @. If it allow unnamed hash ,it can be look nice . We can write DSL using it.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know what DSL is but anyway I cannot see the advantage for me, sorry.  ;-)

Comment: OK, I see what you mean now but unfortunately  I don't have an explanation for you. Sorry.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu That would indeed be handy, but there's no syntax to support it (how would you distinguish a literal hashtable argument from a splatting argument?) - there's an open RFC here: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/issues/6